# How to apply the icon for my popup window in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icons

I have created two windows in my project root folder, `MainWindow.xaml` and `PopupWindow.xaml` respectively.

Through `Project Properties`, I managed to set up an icon for the MainWindow but I couldn't find any available settings for my PopupWindow. Therefore, the PopupWindow is still showing the system default icon in the top left corner.

Can anyone tell me where I can set up a customized icon for my PopupWindow?

Many thanks.

Edit:

I guess I made a mistake in the XMAL code previously. :[
Should have been more careful about the code. Anyways, here is the correct one

`Icon="/[Your Project Name];component/[Your ICO File Name]"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running in Debug mode in Visual Studio? WPF Windows don't inherit their icon from the application in debug mode. Try Ctrl+F5 ("Start Without Debugging") and see if your icons appear.

Comment: Yes I was. But now it seems to be okay :) Thanks for the advice anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

not sure but perhaps this helps
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_xaml_taskbar_window.aspx